# How to disable apt key checking for private repositories under Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, apt, updates, repository, gnupg

Under Ubuntu 14.04 I cannot get this to work.

Our PCI auditor told us we can not have direct outbound access to the Ubuntu repo's, so I mirror them with reprepro. Likewise, we do not have outbound access to keyserver.ubuntu.com.

I have tried adding each of the following to `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99local`:

```
APT::Get::AllowUnauthenticated "true";
APT{Ignore {"gpg-pubkey"; }};
APT { Get { AllowUnauthenticated "1"; }; };
```

And an "apt-get update" still returns, after reading the packages:

```
W: GPG error: hkp://sa1.dal.some-company.com trusty InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 082BCA0181FE8E68
W: GPG error: hkp://sa1.dal.some-company.com trusty-backports InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 082BCA0181FE8E68
W: GPG error: hkp://sa1.dal.some-company.com trusty-security InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 082BCA0181FE8E68
W: GPG error: hkp://sa1.dal.some-company.com trusty-updates InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 082BCA0181FE8E68
```

How can get this to work? Nothing I've found in the documentation on how to disable key checking works.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling signature verification because you installed a local repository is like removing the door locks because you fenced your garden. Don't do this, especially not in environments requiring enhanced security!

You don't need access to a key server to install the public key used for signing packets in reprepro. Simply copy the key file to the respective machine, and import it using a command like

```
sudo apt-key add [publickey]
```

while `[publickey]` is the file containing the key with ID `082BCA0181FE8E68`. You can generate such a file on the computer you generated the key on with

```
gpg --armor --export 082BCA0181FE8E68 >082BCA0181FE8E68.asc
```

The public key can be shared arbitrarily, as it can only be used to verify signatures issued using the private key. Adding the key only needs to be performed once per machine using the repository.

Comment: +1 for the analogy to removing the door locks because of the garden fence!  **Nice one!!!  ;-)**